# How do I raise an exception if an evaluation returns nil in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I want to do something along the lines of this:

```
lookup_value = :f
dict = {a: 20, b: 30, c: 40}
res = dict[lookup_value] | raise 'not found'
```

As in the above example, if the key is not found in the dictionary, I want to raise an error. I *could* just have an additional line which says `raise 'not found' unless res`, but I *really* want to use the lookup in an expression:

```
output = 'prefix' + (dict[lookup_value] | raise 'not found')
```

The problem is that using `raise` in this way is not valid syntax. I am looking for a way that I can raise an error in an expression if the lookup of the value in the hash fails without having to declare additional variables or do a check beforehand.

The following is valid syntax and will throw an exception if the value is not found, but returns nil when a value is found:

```
res = (raise 'not found' unless dict[lookup_value])
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`dict.fetch(lookup_value)` is like `dict[lookup_value]`, but will raise if the key was missing.

You can also do approximately what you have in the question, with a couple of tweaks: `dict[lookup_value] || raise('not found')` -- that gives you control of the exception.

Comment: Thanks, the .fetch solution is great, but I don't understand what you did differently in your second solution. It's the same as what I had in my question, except for the double pipe. It's still invalid syntax (at least in IRB; I haven't tried it in a script).

Comment: The double pipe makes it a short-circuiting 'or'; the parentheses on the `raise` fix the syntax error.

Comment: Oh, brilliant. I didn't notice that little detail! :-) Thanks, answer accepted!

Comment: This would be the only situation where it's acceptable to use `or` over `||`. Can omit the parentheses then too.

Answer (score 3):

This should fix the nil return when a value is found.

Changing this:

```
res = (raise 'not found' unless dict[lookup_value])
```

into this:

```
raise 'not found' unless res = dict[lookup_value]
```

Answer (score 3):

In addition to @matthewd, you can control `raise` with `fetch` in this way:

```
dict.fetch(lookup_value) { raise 'not found' }
```

Comment: No need to add a block here. The documentation says the following: "With no other arguments, it will raise a KeyError exception". https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html#method-i-fetch

Comment: @JohanWentholt yeah, I know it, but as I understand, OP is asking how to raise his own error.

Comment: Ah, I missed that part.

Comment: @JohanWentholt ;)